# add a tabbed view as a main view to a navigation-based iphone app

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

I am relatively new to iOS, hence I apologize for any inconsistency in my question. I need help with the following issue with an app I'm trying to build. My issue is this: The app i am working has a navigation based functionality with a tableview(daily filled by user) and a detailed tableview listing the inputs of the user, but this is just one functionality of the app.
I want to have a main tab based view where one of the tabs(each tab representing a functionality) points to this module.

I wanted to ask for **steps and changes** i need to make to for example **app delegate** or **rootviewcontroller**(I can post the code if it helps better) to make is so that the app starts with a mutli-tabbed bar view where one tab refers to view linked to the ***rootviewontroller*** of the navigation-based app.

**For summary:** Need a main tab bar view where one tab points to the rootviewcontroller highlighted in the screenshot(link below)

If helpful here is a relevant function code i have in app delegate :

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{
    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    RootViewController *rootViewController = (RootViewController *)[[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
    rootViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

    //Next TWO LINES FOR COLOR BACKGROUND

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

}
```

PS:Here is the screenshot for the storyboard: where i would like to have one tab refer to the view(highlighted in the screenshot) which is linked class rootviewcontroller.m/h

**The screenshot:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9AXI.png

**edit:** The actual question can be seen as:  How and what do i need to do to have a **tabbarviewcontroller** which i would add with storyboard **become** my **rootviewcontroller** instead of the navigationcontroller(**highlighted in black in the screenshot**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9AXI.png).

My current rootviewcontroller.m manages anything related to the tableview of the current navigationviewcontroller, do i need to change that also?.

I apologize for excessiv details, I am really new to iOS dev.

---

**From this one** https://i.stack.imgur.com/suLBm.png I tried to embedd in tab barviewcontrol only with storyboard **to this one** https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZxLo.png I tried to embedd in a tab controller just by story but i get an error :**'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController setManagedObjectContext:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8184e30'**

classes related to this are(especially rootviewcontroller.m which is a navigationcontroller for now:

**AppDelegate.{h,m}**
Configures the Core Data stack and the first view controllers.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{
    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    RootViewController *rootViewController = (RootViewController *)[[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
    rootViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;


}
```

**RootViewController.{h,m}**
Manages a table view for listing all values entered. Provides controls for adding and removing these values.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}
```

**DetailViewController.{h,m}**
Manages a detail display for display details of each entered value.

My initial guess is that i need to change the rootviewcontroller **appdidfinishlaunching**.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact now you have:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{
 UITabBarController *tabController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
RootViewController *rootViewController = (RootViewController *)[[[[tabController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0] viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
rootViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

}

Comment: ill put this as a valid answer for now, until i advance in the topic and post an update on the issue. Thank u

Comment: When you update the issue I'll check and see what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

So you actually need a `UITabBarViewController` in the **Storyboard** and you can point to the `UINavigationController` if you want the ability to push other controllers.

You don't need other `UINavigationControllers` as I saw in your screenshot, as long as the `rootviewcontroller` is an `UINavigationController`. 
You can add the `UINavigationController` as first of the tabs and then you can go and fill the other tabs with the viewcontrollers that you need displayed.

SO basically you need to create `UITabBarController` as `rootviewcontroller`.

Let me know if I understood your question correctly.

Here is an example of `UITabBarController` :

```
 - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{
//Here you set your controller
UIViewController* centerController = [[UIViewController alloc]init];

UINavigationController *navCenter = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:centerController] autorelease];

UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];

tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navCenter,nil];

 self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;

return YES;
}
```

Let me know if it worked.

You should have something like this :
[image: This is how it should look]

Comment: Yes, I want to have a tab bar as a rootview for my current app and link one tab to the "navigationcontrolled" currently used as **rootcontroller** in the **screenshot**.tried to do it by the storyboard but it crashes. Any directives on how to do that programaticly? Ill edit the question so as to add the code in **rootviewcontroller.m**

Comment: I tried it but it gives a black screen when i launch but it just shows a black screen...... am i doing something wrong? can you list the steps i need to do to make the change?

Comment: Here is a tutorial I just gave an example there: [uitabartutorial](http://www.xdracco.net/howto-implement-uinavigationcontroller-uitabbarcontroller-programmatically/)

Comment: I see, i am not sure if thats what i need, is there no way to do this with storyboard object components?

Comment: of course it's possible, it's even easier in a storyboard. You add a `UITabBarController` to the sheet , assign it as a `InitialViewController` and then you add a `UINavigationController` to the sheet , an `UIVIewController` and make the `UIViewController` the `rootViewController of the UINavigationController`. Then you drag a line from `UINavigationController` to the `UITabBarController` and pick `viewControllers from the outlet`. it should work.

Comment: im trying to follow the steps, so i added a tabbarcontroller and chose the option to make it initial, and then how do i link it to the storyboard as shown in screenshot?

Comment: keep right click pressed on the navigation controller and drag it to the uitabbarcontroller and pick "viewControllers"

Comment: is your uiviewcontroller the rootviewcontroller of the uinavigationcontroller? if so , then you need to definitely modify something in your former code. the ManagedObjectContext if from CoreData so that is not related.

Comment: yes i have a **tableview** named(rootviewcontroller in the storyboard) embedded in a **navigationController** and has for class **rootviewcontroller.m/h** should i post the code of that class? sorry for long discussion im really new to this.

Comment: I'm not sure we are on the same page. This should be easy to do, if you could post another screenshot so I can see what you did in the storyboard.

Comment: i dragged from tabbar view controller to the navigationviewcontroller which was the initial starting view and and linked it with relation "view controller"  here is the screenshot, but i get the error i talked about earlier. ill post a link shortly

Comment: I understood that, so i posted more details as an answer, can you check on that please?